MatPlotLib histogram not complete?
Im working on a dataset that has 20 features and I wanted to plot their frequency on a histogram. I'm not sure if there's too many, but there aren't enough bars to match the data.
import sklearn
import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib


# Load the dataset
dataset = datasets.load_dataset("rungalileo/20_Newsgroups_Fixed")

#Filtered dataset drops any "none" values
filtered_train = dataset["train"].filter(lambda x: x['label'] != 'None')
filtered_test = dataset["test"].filter(lambda x: x['label'] != 'None')

# Drop 'id'
filtered_test.remove_columns('id')
filtered_train.remove_columns('id')


split_names = dataset.keys()
num_examples = [len(dataset[split]) for split in split_names]


column_values = filtered_train['label']
plt.hist(column_values, orientation='horizontal', rwidth = 0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel("label")
plt.title("Distribution of label")
plt.show()

Incorrect histogram
It didnt fit vertically so I switched it horizontal, then tried to see if the bars were overlapping so I shrunk their size and saw there are only 10 bars.

By default, plt.hist() creates 10 numeric bins.  Your data is categorical (strings, not numbers). A simple solution uses seaborn: import seaborn as sns; sns.countplot(y=column_values); plt.tight_layout(). Or you could try import numpy as np; column_values = [c for c in column_values if c is not None]; plt.hist(column_values, orientation='horizontal', rwidth=0.5, edgecolor='black', bins=np.arange(-0.5, len(np.unique(column_values)))).
